# Which mirrorless have the best live view for night photography?

Tags: focus, low-light, mirrorless

Which mirrorless camera are best suited for focusing (manual is OK) and framing in low-light? I have an Olympus e-pm2, and I can't see anything on the LV when its really dark, and have to resort to tricks and guesswork to get a 2sec iso 6400, f4.0 photo properly focused.
Basically what I'd like is a very sensitive LV or EVF and on-screen focus assistance such as distance and DOF display (I think Fujis do that)

Comment: May be of interest http://petapixel.com/2014/07/04/philip-bloom-compares-eyes-sonys-a7s-beautifully-shot-low-light-video/

Comment: Yeah :) I'm going to start sparing money :) Thanks. 7s seems to have a very sensitive sensor. I could not find any confirmation that it would translate in better LV sensitivity, but that's the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

2 seconds, f4.0 and ISO 6400... You must be in a really dark environment, there. I'm not sure if there's anything that'll be bright enough for that type of lighting environment when in live view, anyway.

However, the Olympus have something called a [Live Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i69JiJj1d2k) feature. It only works in bulb mode but might be something you're after.

Both the OM-D E-M5 & the E-M1 have this feature. They both have a DOF preview as well put probably won't work in low light conditions.

EDIT: You might find that the FujiFilm/Sony A7/A7R are only slightly better than the OM-D.

Comment: It's pretty dark, but there was enough light for my eyes to see what I was photographing. The LV, on the other hand, did not work. 1-2 seconds, with stabilized sensor and some support for my hand, is also within the range where I can still manage to take handheld shots, with some luck :)
I know about live time, thanks - it's a nice feature but I have to focus before taking the image, not during the exposure. Live time mostly helps in getting your exposure right for very long shots. Thanks for mentioning it.
What makes you say that the fuji/sony would only be slightly better?